# How to define result type of anonymous function?

Tags: typescript, functional-programming, mapping

I want to use tuples as result types in `array.map(..)` and I am looking for a way to not define their types upfront as my functions are usually short and result in tuples with only two components.

What is the correct syntax to define the result type of an anonymous function?

Comment: What can I do to improve this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// input
let list: string[] = [ "a", "abc" ]

// possible type definition
type Tuple = [string, number];

// verbose function definition
function hello(s: string): Tuple
{
    return [s, s.length];
}


// different ways to use .map() with 
// same results to show syntax options

let v0 = list.map( s => hello( s ) );

let v1 = list.map( (s: string): Tuple => hello(s) );

let v2 = list.map( (s: string): Tuple => 
{
  return [s, s.length]
});

let v3 = list.map( (s: string): [string, number] => 
{
  return [s, s.length]
});

let v4 = list.map( (s): [string, number] => 
{
  return [s, s.length]
});

let v5 = list.map( (s): [string, number] => [s, s.length] );
```

Try it online with immediate error highlighting [www.typescriptlang.org](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEEsDsAcFcBcCwAoANgU3qV4DO8AuUfAJygHMBtAXVAF5RLQAiAQ2YBoXWAjAY2ahqKFCFDQA9rlzgeGUPACe0dKAAm6AGZRw8cBMgolK0ABVY0eQ0qkKXSLAC2PdCWoBuEcjEA3VzylVTVhIPj0DdS0dcMNkYNCY0AALdFRUCQAKXCJbSHIASiJzS3QUAG8UAEgSTFgSSEZcLlwAOgw8+CSPFABfL1EwNXBNTVd0SCwAd1ZFXAUJUFhcVRbHVmgM-NBJ3STQAeJWR1Ua3FhUeDn4BdwkiUniRQnWAA9QCWgY3C8MLB8ABno2Dw8FW6wyxHoAD5kql0hC5lt8p5kChfqAfABGIE4fBgjagLI5eBkPKFMwWKwwlJpTK4JEotGYDEAJhxIPxEKJxBJFHJxSp+2QFWQoFANXgdQaNmabXG5E6wmQPWRP2ZPgAzOy8WsCdzcgUiDZeXl7E4XG5oUKRWKJVLGrL2gqur1Vai0OqACza0G6rn0o0Gs3OVy0Ogw8ooW21eoO4hyjou5Vupl-ACsPs5hIDjRN5GDFrDMJl8aditAyKAA)